# Export Paw Environments to Postman

Tags: postman, paw-app

I was able to export my Paw collection to Postman via this guide: https://paw.cloud/docs/exporters/postman-exporter

I can't find any information about how to export Paw environments. Is there a way to export Paw environments for use in Postman as well?